# Executing Code in Powershell on Windows10

Tags: powershell, ms-word, signature

my first post. Forgive me if this is posted in the wrong area. 
I'm running a script with :

```
$MSWord = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$fullPath = $LocalSignaturePath+'\'+$SignatureName+'.docx'
$MSWord.Documents.Open($fullPath)
```

I dont have problems running on all other machine except on Windows 10 lately. While running the last line

```
$MSWord.Documents.Open($fullPath)
```

and i got error :

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:3 char:1
+ $MSWord.Documents.Open($fullPath)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

can anyone enlighten me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Word actually installed on the machine?  The error is suggesting that `$MSWord` is not an actual object.  What do you get from the output of `$MSWord | Get-Member`?

Comment: Hi @boxdog! This is what I get:

    TypeName: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass

and yes, MS Word is installed.

Comment: Is this all Windows 10, or a single computer which happens to be Windows 10? I've just tried it here and it works for me. The error says that `$MSWord.Documents` isn't returning anything. `$MSWord.Documents.GetType()` is `__ComObject` for me, presumably it's `$null` for you. Is there anything else odd on that computer - Word is from Office365, Word has never been opened/activated, or anything?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Word has been activated, installed and working perfectly fine. And yes i am beginning to notice this is happening on a new batch of windows 10 pc that i am setting up right now. It is null for me, been googling around for answers and it's been pointing to MSWord issue.

Comment: Interesting; I have no good ideas, just brainstorming .. were the machines imaged? Is it Word 2016? (I'm using 2010 in my test). Have you tried with 'run as administrator' to avoid UAC? Is there any 3rd party AntiVirus engine running which might block script automation? Is it worth trying a repair install of Word on one?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Yes, i have done everything u said actually. Nope, it's not imaged. it's fresh from 'oven', setting up the PC, uninstalling 2016 and reinstalling with 2013. and running as admin. usually i dont have problems on this though, just really stuck here with that presently. i'm guessing it's registry key now that u asked if i was using 2016.

Comment: Could it be Office x86 vs Office x64 edition? 32-bit x86 is typical and recommended..